# trying to get unique list of extension in a directory with a lot of files is going very slowly

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the list of unique extension, and example file of each, in a dataset that is about 9TB and has several hundred thousand files. I try to use the get-child item and it works when I filter to folders that don't have a lot of files but when I filter it to one with a lot of files it seems like it will never start. below are two examples that I have been trying.

```
$Extensions = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$filesReviewed = 0
Get-ChildItem \\server\folder  -Exclude 'excludeFolder'| Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name.Equals('files')} | Get-ChildItem -OutBuffer 1000 |
foreach{
Write-Progress -Activity "Files Reviewed: " -Status "$filesReviewed"
$filesReviewed++ 
if( $Extensions.contains($_.Extension) -eq $False) {
$Extensions.add($_.Extension)
Write-Host $_.Extension
Write-Host $Path = $_.FullName
} 

}
```

I started to try to use dir thinking it might be faster but it has the same problem

```
set-location \\server\folder
dir | dir | Where-Object {$_.Name.Equals('files')} | dir -OutBuffer 10
```

Comment: dir is just an alias for get-childitem

Comment: robocopy with the `\L` "list only" option will give you the list of files somewhat faster than anything built into PoSh. you can tell RC to leave out unwanted  detail & to NOT show any progress to get a bit more speed. parsing the file list is fairly fast ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

`Get-ChildItem` retrieves a lot of info about a file that you don't need in this case and is slowing you down. You could try using `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles` to speed things up

```
$extensions=@{}
[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\server\folder", "*.*", [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) | % 
{
   $extensions[[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]::new($_).Extension]++
} 
$extensions | ft -a
```

Answer (score 2):

you may try the following:

`(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\windows -File -Recurse).Extension | Select-Object -Unique`

Of course, replace the path with the one you would like to use.

More details about get-childitem could be found in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6.

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's an elegant solution, but it is _slow_, given the use of `Select-Object -Unique`; more generally, when performance matters, cmdlets (as opposed to direct use of .NET types) should be avoided altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There are two keys to speeding up your code:

- Avoid the use of the pipeline and therefore avoid using *cmdlets*.

  - If you cannot avoid the pipeline, avoid the use of custom *script blocks* (`{ ... }`), because executing one for every input object is time-consuming.
- Generally, avoid the use of `Write-Progress`, which slows things down noticeably.

---

Avoiding cmdlets requires direct use of  .NET framework types instead.
[Lieven Keersmaekers' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57918001/45375) is a promising start, although combining the pipeline (`%`, i.e. the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet), slows things down, as does the construction of a `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` instance in each iteration, although to a lesser degree.

Note: For brevity and simplicity, the following solution focuses on processing a given directory's entire *subtree* (the equivalent of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File`).

A **performance-optimized solution**:

Note the following aspects:

- `[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles()` rather than `Get-ChildItem` is used to enumerate the files.
- A `foreach` loop rather than the pipeline with the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet (`%`) is used.
- Inside the loop, construction of unnecessary objects is avoided, by calling the static `[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension()` method to extract the filename extension.

```bsh
$seenExtensions=@{}
foreach ($file in [IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($PWD.ProviderPath, '*', 'AllDirectories')) {
  if (-not $seenExtensions.ContainsKey(($ext = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($file)))) {
    $seenExtensions.Add($ext, $true)
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Extension = $ext
      Example = $file
    }
  }
}
```

The above outputs an array of custom objects each representing a unique extension (property `.Extension`) and the path of the first file with that extension encountered (`.Example`).

Sample output (note that the output won't be sorted by extension, but you can simply pipe to `... | Sort-Object Extension`):

```
Extension      Example
---------      -------
.json          C:\temp\foo.json
.txt           C:\temp\sub\bar.txt
...
```

---

**If performance weren't a concern**, PowerShell's cmdlets would allow for a much more elegant solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
  Group-Object Extension |
    Select @{ n='Extension'; e='Name' }, @{ n='Example'; e = { $_.Group[0].Name } }
```

Note that `Group-Object` implicitly sorts the output by the grouping property, so the output will be sorted alphabetically by filename extension.